# Any National ID has an embedded space or any non-number, non-alphabet character in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have column `NationalID` of `varchar(50)` in table A:

```
Worker id   NationalID
BASE00162   844095456
BASE00163   654660468
BASE00164   194543084
```

I have to write a validation SQL query to find any `NationalID` has an embedded space or any non-number, non-alphabet character. It can have hyphens.

I tried `FORMAT()` function but it does not work. Do I need to write function for this?

Comment: `Format` function is supported in SQL Server 2012+

Comment: Some kind of Regexp search?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms179859.aspx). Combine it with [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) to remove the hyphens:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE REPLACE(NationalID, '-', '') LIKE '%[^0-9a-zA-Z]%'
```